# How to forward the values of a tuple? std::get( move(tuple) ) vs. forward( std::get(tuple) )

Tags: c++, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple

Suppose you write something like an "initializer" class, which **stores a set of values** (including references). Those values are then used **to initialize a given type** (e.g. through `my_initializer.initialize<Foo>()`:

```
template<typename... Values>
struct Initializer{
    std::tuple<Values...> values;

    template<typename TypeToInitialize, std::size_t... Is>
    TypeToInitialize initialize_implementation( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
        return { std::get<Is>( this->values )... };
    }

    template<typename TypeToInitialize>
    TypeToInitialize initialize(){
        return initialize_implementation( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Values)>() );
    }
};
```

Pretty straightforward sofa. However, now I want to provide an overload of `initialize()` for **rvalue** objects that gets called whenever the object it is called on is an *rvalue* and the call to `initialize<...>()` is the last action before the object will be destroyed.

**How do I forward the values of a tuple?** Which Option should I pursue?

```
template<typename TypeToInitialize, std::size_t... Is>
TypeToInitialize initialize_move_implementation( std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    // OPTION 1
    return { std::forward<Values>( std::get<Is>( this->values ) )... };

    // OPTION 2
    return { std::get<Is>( std::move( this->values ) )... };
}

template<typename TypeToInitialize>
TypeToInitialize initialize() && {
    return initialize_move_implementation<TypeToInitialize>( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Values)>() );
}
```

Comment: related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38441549/4117728 note that it also mentions `std::make_form_tuple` available since c++17 and it looks like you are building something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename TypeToInitialize>
TypeToInitialize initialize() && {
    return std::make_from_tuple<TypeToInitialize>(this->values);
}
```

Internally, it does something like:

```
return T(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
```

Where `I` is an index sequence like in your original example.

Comment: Shouldn't `this->values` still be explicitly moved?

Comment: Yup, absolutely ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the stored value is of type `T` or `T&&` (suppose `T` is an object type), both options yield `T&&`; if the stored value is of type `T&`, both options yield `T&`, so I don't think there is a difference between the two options. I personally like option 2 because `forward` is usually used along with universal references to forward arguments of a function to another function, while here you are forwarding values stored in a class member, which may be a bit confusing.