# Creating a compile time plugin system with parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a compile-time plugin system for my game engine, but I'm having trouble dealing with passing parameters to each plugin.

Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
#include <tuple>

namespace engine
{
    struct base_plugin
    {
        template<typename EngineT>
        base_plugin(EngineT& engine) {}
        
        ~base_plugin() = default;
    };
    
    template<typename... PluginTs>
    struct engine
    {
        std::tuple<PluginTs...> plugins;
        
        engine() :
            plugins((sizeof(PluginTs), *this)...) {}
    };
}

struct other_plugin
{
    template<typename EngineT>
    other_plugin(EngineT& engine) {}

    ~other_plugin() = default;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    engine::engine<engine::base_plugin, other_plugin> engine;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to be able to accept plugins that have more than the `EngineT&` as parameters. I was thinking of doing this with `tuple`s, but how do I forward each `tuple`'s type to the correct `PluginTs`' constructor?

Comment: where are the parameters coming from? How would main look like when the plugins have parameters?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was thinking of maybe something like `engine::engine<engine::base_plugin, other_plugin> engine(std::make_tuple<int, char**>(argc, argv));`, being one tuple for each plugin, but I'm not too sure. I would be even better if it somehow allowed me to pass in rvalue references to a plugin but I don't think that's possible, since each plugin has a reference to engine, which isn't yet constructed.

Comment: whats wrong with creating the plugins in main and pass the instances to engines constructor? Then that line can be `auto eng = engine::engine(plugin1, plugin2,plugin3,....,pluginN);` and the `engine` needs not know how the plugins are constructed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number How would I pass in the EngineT& reference to the constructor in that example if engine needs to be constructed afterwards?

Comment: btw, dont make the mistake to develop a game-engine without developing a game. Without a usecase you will keep running into similar issues like the current one, that are in fact just design decisions that can be made once you know what are the actual requirements. Just saying....

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That is generally solid advice but I do have a game already made and I'm taking most of the code I can reuse and transforming it into an engine with the game logic as a plugin.

Comment: Don't want to discourage you, but the approach is likely a dead end. It forces you to include all plugins into a single file, which is very bad for compilation times (unless you PIMPL everything?).

Comment: If I understood what you want then this is half way to what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440844/constructor-arguments-from-a-tuple

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not incredibly invested in this solution. I'm just trying to improve my template knowledge in general. I can always try a runtime dispatch approach if needed.

Comment: i would not use templates, I would have an abstract base class

Comment: Just a thought: When I hear "plugin system" I think "runtime loading".  Because if you are a plugin developer, it really sucks to have to rebuild the entire engine every time you change your plugin.  Compile-time plugins also implies shipping a custom version of the engine with a game instead of shipping base engine + plugin binary, which may complicate things.

Comment: @0x5453 While I agree that using this system for the game logic will make rebuilding the whole thing take a greater amount of time, I would argue it would still be useful for enabling/disabling engine components. For example a debug plugin with a debug UI that can be disabled by just changing the engine type's template parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find my answer thanks to the hints from [Constructor arguments from a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440844/constructor-arguments-from-a-tuple). What I needed was a way to construct a plugin with a custom parameter (`EngineT&`) and then unpack the respective `tuple` for the next parameters. Unpacking the `tuple` implies building an `std::index_sequence` with the size of the tuple, using `std::get<Index>` to get the type with that index and finally using ellipsis`...` to do it for all of the tuple's types. This was done with two separate `construct_plugin` functions, one to generate the sequence and one to unpack the tuple using it. In C++17 there is a method that works in a similar way (`std::make_from_tuple`) but since my use case required to inject an extra `EngineT&` parameter at the beginning, it couldn't be used.

I also added a member to engine and some parameters to base_plugin and added some debug prints to verify that everything properly.

Final code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace engine
{
    namespace details
    {
            template<typename PluginT, typename EngineT, typename TupleT, size_t... Is>
            PluginT construct_plugin(EngineT& engine, TupleT&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
            {
                return PluginT(engine, std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleT>(tuple))...);
            }

            template<typename PluginT, typename EngineT, typename TupleT>
            PluginT construct_plugin(EngineT& engine, TupleT&& tuple) 
            {
                return construct_plugin<PluginT>(engine, std::forward<TupleT>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleT>>::value>{});
            }
    }

    struct base_plugin
    {
        template<typename EngineT>
        base_plugin(EngineT& engine, int argc, char* argv[]) 
        {
            std::cout << "Base plugin reports test is " << engine.test << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Base plugin reports argc is " << argc << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Base plugin reports argv is " << argv << std::endl;
        }

        ~base_plugin() = default;
    };
    
    template<typename... PluginTs>
    struct engine
    {
        int test;
        std::tuple<PluginTs...> plugins;

        template<typename... TupleTs>
        engine(TupleTs&&... tuples) :
            test(42),
            plugins(details::construct_plugin<PluginTs>(*this, std::forward<TupleTs>(tuples))...) {}
    };
}

struct other_plugin
{
    template<typename EngineT>
    other_plugin(EngineT& engine) 
    {
        std::cout << "Other plugin reports test is " << engine.test << std::endl;
    }

    ~other_plugin() = default;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    engine::engine<engine::base_plugin, other_plugin> engine(std::make_tuple(argc, argv), std::make_tuple());
    return 0;
}
```